# implementation of recursion and loops at different levels

Tags: algorithm, loops, recursion, hardware

I've read posts where people say certain compilers will implement recursion as loops but the hardware implements loops as recursion and vice versa. If I have a recursive function and an iterative function in my program, can someone please explain how the compiler and hardware are going to interpret each one? Please also address any performance benefits of one over the other if the choice of implementation does not clearly favor one method like using recursion for mergesort.

Comment: It is too broad. It is not possible to say how would an abstract compiler compile an abstract recursive/iterative function.

Comment: It will be easier to say something if you post an example of code.

Comment: I don't have a code example for this. I was just wondering if some compilers convert loop to recursion and others do the opposite and if some hardware implements loops as recursion other hardware does the opposite because I have seen claims for all of the above and I don't know if everyone is right in certain cases or if some are mistaken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here is a brief answer:

1)A compiler can optimize tail recursive calls. But it is usually not a loop, but rather a stack frame reuse. However, I have never heard of any compiler that converts a loop into recursion(and I do not see any point of doing so: it would use additional stack space, likely to work slower and can lead to the change of semantics(stackoverflow instead of an infinite loop)).

2)I would say that it is not correct to speak about hardware implementing loops, because hardware itself does not implement loops. It has instructions(like conditional jumps, arithmetical operations and so on) which are used to implement loops.